# Android propagating exception performance

Tags: android, exception

I'm interested how much slower it will be if I propagate exception up to call stack thru 3 methods and if is something like that very strange, or is any better way to achieve this.

Here is sample of code what I mean:

```
final static Exception myException=new Exception();
    private void method1() {
        try{
            method2();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //do something because of this exception
        }


    }
    private void method2() throws Exception {
        //some code
        method3();


    }
    private void method3() throws Exception {
        //some code
        method4();

    }
    private void method4() throws Exception {
        try{
            //some code, which came to IO exception if is anything wrong
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw myException;
        }
    }
```

In reality all method have their own return type which one I wouldn't like to change just for telling that was an exception, if that is not necessary.